# VBA code to clear just constants on destination sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have filtered my cumulative sales from SalesMasterSheet to different sheets each named after each particular customer but I got stuck at trying to add excel formulas because my VBA code always clears content of the range of cells on sheetActive.

I have tried the special cell method so as to clear only constants but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.
below is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_activate()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("ACCIMA").Range("A1:L500").ClearContents

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C").Value = "ACCIMA" Then
       Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Copy _ 
              Destination:=Sheets("ACCIMA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

So far what it does is copy entries with "ACCIMA" on column C from Mastersheet to sheet("ACCIMA"), but i would like to put a formula in sheet("ACCIMA") but because `Sheets("ACCIMA").Range("A1:L500").ClearContents`
all formulas clear once i make the sheet active.

Comment: please share your code and some sample data/show us your data layout. We can't see your screen.

Comment: I've shared my code, thanks.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you want.  You cannot determine if a cell value is "constant" in VBA.  Where are you putting the formula?  Row 1?  If so you could change `Sheets("ACCIMA").Range("A1:L500").ClearContents` to `Sheets("ACCIMA").Range("A2:L500").ClearContents`.  Either way, you need to properly define what you're trying to do.

Comment: i want the formula on column L. but even when i change the code from Sheets("ACCIMA").Range("A1:L500").ClearContents to Sheets("ACCIMA").Range("A1:K500").ClearContents it still clears formula on column L aswell i think maybe because of this line Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Copy tries to copy the entire row. please how do i get around this.

Comment: How do i substitute a range instead of entireRow on this line of code   'Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Copy'

Answer (score 0):

Given the low amount of informations you give I sort of understood your problem this way:

If your code always clears content of the range of cells on the active sheet you should try to add the worksheet you are working on in your code, e.g.

```
 cells(1,1).value = "test"
```

would turn into

```
worksheets("customer1").cells(1,1).value = "test"
```

---

After new informations:

Copy the content of your range "A1:K500", ignore the column "L" which has your formular and then add your formulars in column "L".

```
worksheets("customer1").cells(1,1).formula = "..."
```

Keep in mind, that your syntax for the formula changes in comparison with the synatx on the actual excel sheet.
e.g.:

```
 =IF(A1="empty";"empty";"not empty")
```

Will turn into:

```
worksheets("customer1").cells(1,1).formula = "=IF(A1=""empty"",""empty"",""not empty"")"
```

Comment: Why don't you copy your cells except for Column "L" and then you hardcode your column "L" as a formular? I'll edit my post to show you.